# Newlines and blank lines formatting in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to prevent the autoformatter from removing newlines in the comments and blank lines in the code?

Comment: Have you looked in the code format options?

Comment: Is this about Java sources?

Comment: @nitind The OP doesn't mention it explicitly, but the question is tagged "Java", so it's a fair assumption that we're talking about the Java editor here.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse go to **Preferences - Java - Code Style - Formatter** and Edit your Active Profile:

[image]

Go the the **Blank Lines** tab, and set **Number of empty lines to preserve:** to however many blank lines you'd like Eclipse to keep:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows>Preferences>java>Code Style>Formatter
Click on new
 mention profile name then ok

Select Blank Lines Tabs. And customize blank line settings according to you.
click on apply ...